# Static objects are not always there when a GCM message is received

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing GCM into my Android app. So far so good, the messaging works, but when a message is received, the app may or may not crash with `NullPointerException`. The reason this happens is because a static reference is sometimes `null` and sometimes not, but the reason why this happens is unknown to me.

The object that may or may not be null is a `MessageController` located via a simple service locator pattern, which looks like this:

```
public class ControllerLocator
{
    private static MessageController controller; 

    public static MessageController getMessageController()
    {
        return controller;
    }

    public static void provide(MessageController mc)
    {
        controller = mc;
    }
}
```

The controller is set up in the application's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    ControllerLocator.provide(new MessageController());
}

// Later on in the program after backend authentication:
ControllerLocator.getMessageController().setCredentials(...);
```

The GCM message handling is like this:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msgType = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this).getMessageType(intent);
    if(msgType.equals(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE))
    {
        handleMessage(extras.getString("message"));
    }

    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void handleMessage(String msg)
{
    // 'controller' may or may not be null
    MessageController controller = ControllerLocator.getMessageController();
}
```

Now, the actual scenario: Everything works fine when the app is running in the foreground. However, if I press "back" to exit close the main activity and a GCM message is received, the crash may or may not occur.

Why does the static reference get removed? How would I fix this to ensure that the controller is always there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your app process is killed and all the memory it held was released while you were waiting for that GCM message.
When your GCM message was incoming the system creates your app process and Application object over again hence you got null.

Simply check if the instance is null on your get instance method and if its null recreate your object.

EDIT:
There is no way to make sure the same object is alive always, Android system is running many apps at once and cant allow any app to fill up memory, therefore it may kill your process whenever other apps need memory and that would automatically release your reserved memory including static varaiables. Its your job as an Android developer to deal with it :)

To avoid reauth and heavy computations on recreation, you may have to rethink your design such that the state of your object is persistent, using SharedPreferences maybe.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the resources? There's the whole authentication chain that has to be redone in this case.

Comment: In addition please use GcmListenerService instead of doing your own wakeful intent.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `MessageController` variable static.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. This should be a comment instead.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow doesn't allow me comment yet! :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ensure that your static Controller Object will be alive (*not null*),, Because an app in the background is an ideal candidate for GC.

You could however save your GCM Message data in `SQLite` at the point where it is received. And then check the table for data, when you open your app.